# I want to do a Cronjob but I got some Errors

Tags: linux, debian, cron

I got some errors in my cron job and I don't know why. In my cron job is this:

[image]

and I got those errors when my cron job is trying to start my script but I don't understand `Error: bad username` error because `mc` is a valid user in my system and got the rights for the folder.

Errors:

```
Apr  2 21:34:55 Debian-78-wheezy-64-minimal /usr/sbin/cron[27104]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Apr  2 21:34:55 Debian-78-wheezy-64-minimal /usr/sbin/cron[27105]: (CRON) STARTUP (fork ok)
Apr  2 21:34:55 Debian-78-wheezy-64-minimal cron[27105]: Error: bad username; while reading /etc/crontab
Apr  2 21:34:55 Debian-78-wheezy-64-minimal /usr/sbin/cron[27105]: (*system*) ERROR (Syntax error, this crontab file will be ignored)
Apr  2 21:34:55 Debian-78-wheezy-64-minimal /usr/sbin/cron[27105]: (CRON) INFO (Skipping @reboot jobs -- not system startup)
```

Comment: Can you post `ls -l /home/`?

Comment: Yes and thank you for editing my Thread :D

Here the output:

http://puu.sh/gZfcx/4b19004947.png

Comment: I think, the @reboot-line is wrong: there, it looks for the user `cd`. try again, commenting that line

Comment: Friendly suggestion - in the future, you should type out code whenever possible instead of using screenshots. It'll help you avoid any undue criticism =)

Comment: @CodeMoose: Yes, but don't type it. Copy-and-paste it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have probably corrupted your `crontab` file. Edit it with `crontab -e` and try to add an empty new line at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think the bad username it's complaining about is `cd` in the `@reboot` line.

A system crontab is like a user crontab except that you need to provide a username after the time and date fields and before the commands.

Normally there are 5 time and date fields, but they can be replaced by a single field `@reboot` (or `@daily`, `@weekly`, and several other options). You still need the username field.

Add a user name after `@reboot` (I don't know whether you want `root`, `mc`, or something else

(I'm not 100% sure of my interpretation; I haven't tried using `@` fields in a system crontab.)

Aside from that, it's generally a good idea to use your personal crontab, not `/etc/crontab`, for commands you want to run under  your own account. Assuming your username is `mc`, you can create a file like this:

```
1 * * * * some_command
```

and then feed that file to the `crontab` command.

By putting personal commands in `/etc/crontab`, you risk messing up the rest of the file and possibly damaging the system as a whole. And you have to be `root` to edit `/etc/crontab`; don't use the `root` account for anything that doesn't require it.

Comment: Thanks Keith but this isnt anymore my prob :) My prob is now That my script isnt running but idk why. My cron is doing his job fine, read again my last Answer pls and Reply to me :)

Comment: As far as I can tell, what you posted as an answer did not actually answer the question. You said "Ok I got it now", but you didn't say how you fixed it. If you post an answer that explains what the actual solution was, it will be useful to others. If your crontab problem has been solved and you now have a different problem, you should post a new question.

Comment: Lol i said my solution i edited the Crontab file again with crontab -e so my Crontab file isnt corrupted anymore. But my Problem is now that cronjob want to start my Script. You can see my Script above. And the Actual Cron.log too

Comment: @oRxx: And we have no idea how you fixed it or what the original problem was. (When you used `crontab -e`, did you change the `@reboot` line as I suggested?) If you have a new problem, please post a new question.